# create new dataframe based on group by and aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `matches` containing match results as follows:

```
year    winner      loser   score
1990    A           B       6-0
1990    B           C       5-0 RET
1990    A           B       4-0 RET
1990    C           C       6-0
1991    A           B       6-1
1991    A           C       4-1 RET
1991    B           A       6-4
1991    C           A       3-0 RET
```

I want to create a new dataframe containing *wins*, *losses*, and *wins by retirement* for each player per year.
The final output shoud look like:

```
year    player      wins    losses      rets
1990    A           2       0           1
1990    B           1       2           1
1990    C           1       2           0
1991    A           2       2           1
1991    B           1       1           0
1991    C           1       1           1
```

For wins and losses I can do this successfully.
I do:

```
w_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'winner']).size()
l_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'loser']).size()
```

And then create a new dataframe:

```
scores = pd.DataFrame({'wins' : w_group, 'losses' : l_group}).fillna(0)
#name the index
scores.index.names = ['year','player']
```

However, for calculating the wins via retirement I dont know how to achieve the column. I tried this:

```
ret_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'winner']).apply(lambda x: x[(x['score'].str.contains('RET').fillna(False))].count())
```

But this gives me the following exception:

```
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: '[ 0.] not in index'
```

Your solution is highly appreciated

Comment: Your code works for me (Python 3.4.3, pandas 0.16.2).

Comment: does it yield the expected result? that is, a new dataframe with the columns, wins/losses/rets?

Comment: I get a data frame with the following columns: `'year', 'winner', 'loser', 'score'`, and `'score'` holds the result you're looking for (`[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`).

Comment: hm. i wann reach this. read above "The final output shoud look like:" this is what i need.

Comment: But then all you have to do is `scores['rets'] = ret_group['score']`. Your biggest problem is the error you get and that I can't reproduce, right?

Comment: yep. I get this error. it's strange.

However, I found another solution which works: `ret_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'winner']).apply(lambda x: (x['score'].str.contains('RET').fillna(False)).sum())`

thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
ret_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'winner']).apply(lambda x: x[(x['score'].str.contains('RET').fillna(False))].count())
```

to

```
ret_group = matches.groupby(['year', 'winner']).apply(lambda x: (x['score'].str.contains('RET').fillna(False)).sum())
```

Now it works.